# How to combine UISlider and CollectionView to autoresizing the cells of the UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uikit

I need to create the next UI

[User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAxfn.jpg)

But i don't know where to start and how does the UISlider update the CollectionView's cells.

The idea is to use a ramdom JSON and render each item into the CollectionView's cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Set default value of how many cells to be displayed per row.
var numberOfItemsPerRow:Int = 4

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureSlider()
}
func configureSlider() {
    let slider = UISlider(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 20))
    slider.center = self.view.center
    // minimum number of rows required
    slider.maximumValue = 1
    // maximum number of rows required
    slider.maximumValue = 10
    slider.value = 1
    slider.isContinuous = true
    stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(stepper)
    numberOfItemsPerRow = Int(stepper.value)
}

@objc func sliderValueChanged(_ sender:UISlider!) {
    numberOfItemsPerRow  = Int(sender.value)
    
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (self.view.frame.width)/CGFloat(numberOfItemsPerRow)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}
```

Hope you can configure remaining delegate methods.

Comment: I really appreciate you help, but you use a stepper: UIStepper(). 

How does the code look if it would be a Slider : UISlider

Comment: UIStepper and UISlider share same concept behind the scenes !! I've update the code with UISlider.

Comment: You save my day

Comment: Good to hear !  Kindly accept it and upvote the answer !! Thank you !! Happy coding..